# Calling json function in wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress

In my wordpress plugin I need to have a JSON option to load, using jquery, info about a custom post type. This jquery call will come in a page where all users should see it.

as far as i understand from the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) I should have a function:

```
function my_json_returning_function(){
    // get json objects here
    echo $json;
    die();
}
```

As well as the actions:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_json_action', 'my_json_returning_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_json_action', 'my_json_returning_function');
```

All in my plugin file.

then something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'my_json_action',
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>, data, function(response) {
         alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

should call the function in question.

My real question is where i should place all the different parts - and if something is missing.

The php function and the actions hooks go into the plugin file. But the javascript I am more confused about. I want to put it in the plugin javascript file, but since i have to fetch the admin url using php that becomes a problem.

Also how do I make sure that the script is only called if in a certain page? Are there more hooks and filters I should be comfortable with? Or is it possible to load it using wp_enqueue_script when executing a shortcode on that page, or is that to late, as I would seem it needs to be loaded in the header.

A lot of questions, but I hope you understand the basis of my problem - I have a hard time placing the code in the right places in the wordpress structure.

**EDIT:**
Calling echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); is not, at least in my eyes the most elegant way of doing it. I'd rather have a json API, with its seperate url, and calling it in the ajax call. How would I go about setting up a page in wordpress that only returns a json object?

Comment: This question [has been answered on the WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/how-to-manage-ajax-calls-and-json-in-wordpress). The trick is that you can use `wp_localize_script()` to send PHP configuration values to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

What you have above is partially correct.

when using the call to admin-ajax.php, you have in the comments from the wordpress codex page is

```
// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header  
// and points to admin-ajax.php
```

this is just it... use the javascript variable '**ajaxurl**' in place of the php call..

so it would look like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var data = {
    action: 'my_json_action',
};

  // since 2.8 ajaxurl
  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
     alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
  });
});
```

that should be you.. just place all your functions inside your main plugin file.
when wordpress loads it will produce a variable called ajaxurl that you can then use in your scripts.. :)

Comment: Yes, But as I understood it it would only be valid on an admin page, aand this is supposed to be on a regular page for everyone to see. So the ajaxurl wouldn't be defined.
But, out of curiosity, where would you place the jquery function in your example?

Comment: well in this instance if it was a plugin i was creating i would place this in the main plugin .php page, the way i normaly do it would be to create a new php file within my plugin folder structure, named wp-jquery.php within this file would be my call to the add_action hooks ie: wp_ajax_MYFUNCTION also using the wp_ajax_nopriv_MYFUNCTION which allows the call to the file while on the front end, then inside my main plugin .php page i would include that file. ie: include('inc/wp-jquery.php'); post here which might help http://geekpreneur.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-wpajax-in-wordpress.html